# javaCV ffmpeg Android N Linker error

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm hoping I can get some help on an issue I cannot seem to solve.  I am trying to use javaCV FFmpegFrameGrabber to capture an RTSP stream.  I have followed the instructions on configuring javaCV manually.  I have ffmpeg.jar, javacv.jar, and javacpp.jar in the libs folder and the .so files in jniLibs/armeabi-v7a.  I am using javaCV version 1.3.1.

When I Run the application on a device running Android 5.0.1, it runs fine, but I've tried it on several devices running Android 7+ and I consistently get the error:

> E/linker: library "/system/lib/libdl.so" ("/system/lib/libdl.so")
>   needed or dlopened by "/system/lib/libnativeloader.so" is not
>   accessible for the namespace:

Any suggestions on how to get this working on Android 7+?

Comment: Could you show the few lines of log before and after as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out [The UnsatisfiedLinkError X File (a real experience)](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/The-UnsatisfiedLinkError-X-File-(a-real-experience))
It solved my problem on Samsun S4 with Android 5.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  I am actually using Relinker, and it works on GS 4.  My issue is with Android N devices (My test devices are a Nexus 6P and Google Pixel).

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer, but I needed to add an additional step.  I had to expand javacpp.jar, remove the following files: remove 4 properties files - android-arm.properties, android-x86.properties, android-arm-64.properties, android-x86_64.properties, and re-jar it.  Once that was done, it runs on a Google Pixel running Android 7.1